# NLP: What are some popular packages for phrase tokenization?

Tags: nlp, nltk, tokenization

I'm trying to tokenize some sentences into phrases. For instance, given

> I think you're cute and I want to know more about you

The tokens can be something like

> I think you're cute

and

> I want to know more about you

Similarly, given input

> Today was great, but the weather could have been better.

Tokens:

> Today was great

and

> the weather could have been better

Can NLTK or similar packages achieve this?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spacy can do this. Spacy's semantic parser is based on Language models trained on large corpus of text.

This parser can break sentence into lower level components such as words / phrases.

More details and examples :

https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features

Example with the first sentence from  questions: https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=I%20think%20you%27re%20cute%20and%20I%20want%20to%20know%20more%20about%20you&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look at semantic parsing, but it's not clear how to identify phrases. For instance, in my first sentence, a semantic parser can identify 'and' as `CCONJ` and 'think' and 'want' are connected by `conj`. It's not clear where the phrase boundaries actually are though. Is there a way to interpret the components to extract the boundaries?

Comment: This is an example of parsing sub-trees.  https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/information_extraction/parse_subtrees.py    I suggest that you try this example of few sentences and see if this works for your corpus.